# Google Cloud Function outgoing call using Static IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, static-ip-address

I am calling an external service from my cloud function that only allows requests from whitelisted IP addresses.

In such case I've followed the following steps mentioned in article 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip

But when I am executing the cloud function the external service receiving the call from IP 0.0.0.0(which I can see default internet gateway) instead of my reserved static IP.

Can you please guide me the steps if I missed anything.

Comment: It is possible, but you need to use a VPC connector for your cloud functions, this connector allows your functions to reach the IP addresses in your project.

After deploying your VPC connector your cloud functions can reach a virtual machine that would act as an outbound traffic proxy for your cloud functions, virtual machines can be configured to use a public static IP, this might be a good approach, but more expensive and complicated than move your function to a virtual machine

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc

Comment: 've setup cloud NAT properly also internet connection has been established in clod function. but I found it always taking 0.0.0.0 as internet broadcast IP \, not the static IP which I've patched on cloud Nat. Can you help me to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean my new http calls ? My cloud function implementation call an external API endpoint. so when I trigger cloud function it always hits that API endpoint.  But it always did with brodcast IP 0.0.0.0 instead of cloud NAT public IP